# Doctrine Query doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine. I have a form in which the user writes `start date` and selects some categories with checkboxes. The items in the database table have date field and category field. What I want to do is to make a query for the items with categories from the checked ones and with date after the start date selected. So I wrote a method like this:

```
public function findForCatsAndTimes($user, $q)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e FROM AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Expense e WHERE e.user = ?1'.$q);
    $query->setParameter(1, $user);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

in order easily to write the different queries in the controller and not to make 1000 methods for each case.

I take the selected categories by the user in an array called `$cats`.
And the selected date in a variable called `$start_date`.

```
$query = '';

if( $start_date != ""){
    $query .= ' AND (e.date > '.$start_date.')';
}

        $query .='AND (e.category='.$cats[0];

        array_shift($cats);
        foreach ($cats as $c)
        {
            $query .= ' OR e.category='.$c;
        }

        $query .= ')';  

$response = $repo->findForCatsAndTimes($this->user, $query);
```

This works fine for the categories, but don't work for the date. It just selects all items of the selected categories, no matter what the date is.

I get this when I execute `echo $query`:

```
AND (e.date > 23-05-2013)AND (e.category=48 OR e.category=49)
```

and this when I var_dump `$start_date`:
string(10) "23-05-2013"

(my start_date field in the db is string, not date object)

But when I see DB queries from the Symfony Profiler I get this:

```
SELECT 
  e0_.id AS id0, 
  e0_.product AS product1, 
  e0_.description AS description2, 
  e0_.price AS price3, 
  e0_.date AS date4, 
  e0_.fos_user_id AS fos_user_id5, 
  e0_.category_id AS category_id6 
FROM 
  expense e0_ 
WHERE 
  e0_.fos_user_id = ? AND (
    e0_.date > 23 - 05 - 2013 
  ) AND (
    e0_.category_id = 48 OR e0_.category_id = 49 
  )
```

There are some strange spaces between the dashes :(

This query

```
public function findBetweenDates($user, $date1, $date2)
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.date >= :date1')
        ->andWhere('e.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('e.date <= :date2')
        ->setParameter('date1', $date1)
        ->setParameter('date2', $date2)
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
         ->getQuery();

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

called like this works fine:

```
$exp = $repo->findBetweenDates($this->user, '14-05-2013', '21-05-2013');
```

I guess the problem comes from the strange spaces, but I don't know what to do to fix this, or from where they came. :(

Any ideas for solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever use strings for storing dates. Especially not like this. If your query worked, it still would result in unexpected stuff, because when matching strings it works in an alphabetic order. So in your case you would get all dates after the 23rd of any month and any year. So you need to store them as DATETIME in order to solve this. The other problem is that you need to put $start_date between apostrophes, because now it calculates 23-5-2013, which is -1995. So:

1. Convert the dates to `DATETIME`;
2. Use `\DateTime` objects when inserting and querying (and YYYY-MM-DD format for strings)

Oh, and one more thing: use [IN](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion) expressions in your where condition, it's much more practical.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! The reason my dates are strings is because in forms with datetime fields Chrome outputs its own datepicker and I wanted to avoid it. But I guess it's not reasonable enough. I'll use datetime. :)